# how does android draw its mouse cursor

Tags: android, events, cursor, mouse, draw

Basically I want to make a **native app** or **service** or **event throw adb**, to draw some cursor on top of the whole android screen, just like what the mouse cursor does. But I do not know how to draw that thing. I have a ROOTED tablet and its cross compiler. Is there any simple way to do that? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System wide, I doubt this is possible, app wide, this should be possible. Drawing ontop of a canvas would be a good start.

Comment: Thank you for you help, but I still need to do it in system wide. I am thinking of maybe the openGL ES surface can overlay on top of the java surface, I don't know.

Comment: Good luck, that is quite a task.. Probably have to do with the WindowManager. Also just so you know, a rooted phone cannot do anything like this. You have to rebuild the entire source code from the phone and change it. Which is not possible unless you have the source.

Comment: I heard of "modifying the WindowManager", but I do not really understand the meanning of "modify". Do I need to change the android source code and re-build it?

Comment: I see..... thank you any way. Please allow me to wait some more answers for some days.